# Как в python kivy создать приложение с неограниченным числом экранов

Tags: python, kivy, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Я уже долгое время не могу найти объяснение, как на kivy сделать приложение, например какой-нибудь блокнот, чтобы в нём пользователь мог бесконечно создавать новые записи, и чтобы каждую можно было в этом же приложении перейти и открыть.
То есть все элементы (кнопки в меню, означающие каждая свою запись, и ведущая на свой собственный экран, на котором можно было бы прочесть и изменить текст) заранее создать нельзя, так-как они должны добавляться самим пользователем по его желанию (захочет, создаст себе ещё один, захочет, удалит).

Я попытался сделать это через громоздкое приписывание и удаление в сам файл python и kv новых классов и элементов для каждой добавленной или удалённой записи, которые добавляются при нахождении определенного знака в коде и во время этого ещё считывают последний номер элемента до себя.
Всю это как-то работает, но после каждой добавленной или удалённой записи, приходится перезапустить весь скрипт, чтобы изменения вступили в силу, да и при малейшей перестановке элементов всё ломается.

вот весь этот код, если кому интересно:

adder.py:

```
import re

pattern1 = "class TextWindow"
pattern2 = "# ormhldmbrlgpfbk5bdf4bpvbps"
def add_window():

    f = open("main.py", "r+", encoding="utf-8")

    content1 = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    content2 = []
    c = 1

    for i in content1:
        if re.search(pattern1, i):
            c = re.findall("\d+", i)[0]
            c = int(c) + 1

        if re.search(pattern2, i):
            content2.append(f"class TextWindow{c}(Screen):\n")
            content2.append("   def load_text(self, input, nu):\n")
            content2.append("       standard_load_text(self, input, nu)\n")
            content2.append("   def save_text(self, input, nu):\n")
            content2.append("       standard_save_text(self, input, nu)\n")
            content2.append("   def delete_text(self, nu):\n")
            content2.append("       standard_delete_text(self, nu)\n")
            content2.append("\n")
            content2.append("# ormhldmbrlgpfbk5bdf4bpvbps\n")

        else:
            content2.append(i)


    print(content2)

    f = open("main.py", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    for i in content2:
        f.write(i)
    f.close()

def delete_window(nu):
    f = open("main.py", "r+", encoding="utf-8")

    content1 = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    content2 = []
    delete_class = False
    cdc = 0
    fukcing_cocoynter = 0

    for i in content1:
        if re.search(f"class TextWindow{nu}", i) and cdc == 0:
            delete_class = True
            cdc = 1

        if re.search("class TextWindow", i) and fukcing_cocoynter >= 7:
            delete_class = False

        if re.search(pattern2, i):
            delete_class = False

        if not delete_class:
            content2.append(i)

        if delete_class:
            fukcing_cocoynter += 1

    print(content2)

    f = open("main.py", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    for i in content2:
        f.write(i)
    f.close()
```

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
import sys
import os
import re
import adder
import importlib


Window.size = (500, 750)
Window.clearcolor = (12/255, 12/255, 12/255, 1)
Window.title = "Блокнот с подвохом"

number_of_box = 0 
notebook = "#krmbfgrlp45-lh5-hkogkr94jg94gpoekfp309"
names_on_core = "#glrmblfbpel543fidfj03"
name_of_screen = "cjgermdlpwefekl13421"
call_name_of_screen = "dgdghfhhlhp4p3fdf"
name_of_notebook = "lfgglc24fovld4oglp6lf"
exist = "[A-Za-z1-9А-Яа-я]"
button_on_menu = "#lgplveiok3203kov0303vojIJVO"
title_of_button_on_menu = "#oelpfb66koojhhfikckckkck"


class ChoiceMenu1(Screen):
    def title_on_menu(self, input, nu):
        standard_title_on_menu(self, input, nu)

    def create_notebook(self, **kwargs):
        f = open("new_windows.kv", "r+", encoding="utf-8")

        content1 = f.readlines()
        f.close()

        content2 = []
        kal = 0
        cou = 1
        coub = 1
        cout = 1
        cott = 1

        for i in content1:

            if re.search(exist, i) and not re.search(button_on_menu, i) and not re.search(notebook, i)\
                    and not re.search(title_of_button_on_menu, i):
                content2.append(i)
                if re.search("TextWindow", i):
                    cou = re.findall("\d+", i)[0]
                    cou = int(cou) + 1

            if not re.search(exist, i) and kal == 0 and not re.search(title_of_button_on_menu, i):
                content2.append(f"    TextWindow{cou}:\n")
                content2.append(" \n")
                kal = 1

            if re.search("Button: #", i):
                coub = re.findall("\d+", i)[0]
                coub = int(coub) + 1

            if re.search("<TextWindow", i):
                cout = re.findall("\d+", i)[0]
                cout = int(cout) + 1

            if re.search("root.title_on_menu", i):
                cott = re.findall("\d+", i)[0]
                cott = int(cott) + 1

            if re.search(title_of_button_on_menu, i):
                content2.append(f"        root.title_on_menu(notebook_{cott}, {cott})\n")
                content2.append("        #oelpfb66koojhhfikckckkck\n")

            if re.search(button_on_menu, i):
                content2.append(f"            Button: #{coub}\n")
                content2.append("                size_hint: 1, None\n")
                content2.append("                size: 0, 60\n")
                content2.append("                font_size: 19\n")
                content2.append("                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.6, 0.9, 0.9, 1)\n")
                content2.append(f"                id: notebook_{coub}\n")
                content2.append("                on_release:\n")
                content2.append(f"                    app.root.current = '{coub} notebook'\n")
                content2.append("                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'\n")
                content2.append("\n")
                content2.append("           #lgplveiok3203kov0303vojIJVO\n")
                content2.append("\n")

            if re.search(notebook, i):
                content2.append(f"<TextWindow{cout}>:\n")
                content2.append(f"    name: '{cout} notebook'\n")
                content2.append("    on_pre_enter:\n")
                content2.append(f"        root.load_text(text_input, {cout})\n")
                content2.append("    BoxLayout:\n")
                content2.append("        pos_hint: {'top': 1}\n")
                content2.append("        size_hint: 1, 0.08\n")
                content2.append("        padding: 5\n")
                content2.append("        spacing: 5\n")
                content2.append("        orientation: 'horizontal'\n")
                content2.append("        size: root.width, root.height\n")
                content2.append("        Button:\n")
                content2.append("            size_hint: 1, 1\n")
                content2.append("            text: 'Сохранить'\n")
                content2.append("            font_size: 20\n")
                content2.append("            background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)\n")
                content2.append("            on_release:\n")
                content2.append("                app.root.current = 'choice_menu'\n")
                content2.append("                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'\n")
                content2.append("            on_press:\n")
                content2.append(f"                root.save_text(text_input, {cout})\n")
                content2.append("        Button:\n")
                content2.append("            size_hint: 1, 1\n")
                content2.append("            text: 'Удалить'\n")
                content2.append("            font_size: 20\n")
                content2.append("            background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)\n")
                content2.append("            on_release:\n")
                content2.append("                app.root.current = 'choice_menu'\n")
                content2.append("                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'\n")
                content2.append('            on_press:\n')
                content2.append(f'                root.delete_text({cout})\n')
                content2.append("    BoxLayout:\n")
                content2.append("        pos_hint: {'top': 0.92}\n")
                content2.append("        size_hint: 1, 0.92\n")
                content2.append("        orientation: 'vertical'\n")
                content2.append("        size: root.width, root.height\n")
                content2.append("        TextInput:\n")
                content2.append("            font_size: 20\n")
                content2.append("            id: text_input\n")
                content2.append("            background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)\n")
                content2.append("            foreground_color: (255, 255, 255, 1)\n")

                content2.append("\n")
                content2.append("#krmbfgrlp45-lh5-hkogkr94jg94gpoekfp309\n")
                content2.append("\n")

        print(content2)

        adder.add_window()

        f = open("new_windows.kv", "w", encoding="utf-8")
        for i in content2:
           f.write(i)
        f.close()



def standard_load_text(self, input, nu):
    if os.path.exists(f'{nu}_notebook.txt'):
        f = open(f'{nu}_notebook.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
        input.text = f.read()
        f.close()

def standard_save_text(self, input, nu):
    text = input.text
    f = open(f'{nu}_notebook.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(text)
    f.close()
    print(text)

def standard_title_on_menu(self, input, nu):
    try:
        f = open(f'{nu}_notebook.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
        input.text = f.readline(48)
        f.close()
    except:
        pass

def standard_delete_text(self, nu):
    if os.path.exists(f'{nu}_notebook.txt'):
        os.remove(f'{nu}_notebook.txt')


    f = open("new_windows.kv", "r+", encoding="utf-8")

    content1 = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    content2 = []
    cw = 0
    cd = 0
    cb = 0
    boring = 0
    boring2 = 0
    delete_ = False
    delete_in_up = False
    button_activate = False
    delete_title_text = False


    for i in content1:

        if re.search(f"Button: #{nu}", i) and cb == 0 and not button_activate:
            button_activate = True
            cb = 1

        if re.search("Button:", i) and not re.search(f"Button: #{nu}", i):
            button_activate = False

        if re.search(button_on_menu, i):
            button_activate = False

        if re.search(f"TextWindow{nu}:", i) and cd == 0 and not delete_in_up and not button_activate:
            delete_in_up = True
            cd = 1

        if re.search(notebook, i) and not delete_in_up and not button_activate:
            delete_ = False
            cw = 0

        if re.search("<TextWindow", i) and not delete_in_up and not button_activate:
            cw += 1
            delete_ = False
            cot = re.findall("\d+", i)[0]
            cot = int(cot)

            if cot == nu and boring == 0:
                delete_ = True
                cw = 0
                boring = 1
            else:
                content2.append(i)

        if re.search(f"notebook_{nu}, {nu}", i) and boring2 == 0:
            delete_title_text = True
            boring2 = 1

        if not delete_ and not re.search("<TextWindow", i) and not delete_in_up and not button_activate\
                and not delete_title_text:
            content2.append(i)

        delete_in_up = False
        delete_title_text = False

    f = open("new_windows.kv", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    for i in content2:
       f.write(i)
    f.close()

    adder.delete_window(nu)


class Crutch1(Screen):
    pass


# ormhldmbrlgpfbk5bdf4bpvbps


class ChoiceWindow(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("new_windows.kv")

class GayApp1(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_ = GayApp1().run()
```

new_windows.kv:

```
ChoiceWindow:
    Crutch1:
    ChoiceMenu1:
 
<Crutch1>:
    name: "crutch"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            text: "Блокнот с подвохом"
            font_size: 40
            background_color: (0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'choice_menu'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
<ChoiceMenu1>:
    name: "choice_menu" # имя по которому откликается
    on_pre_enter:
        #oelpfb66koojhhfikckckkck
    ScrollView:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.9}
        size_hint_y: 0.9
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height:self.minimum_height
            padding: 5
            spacing: 10

           #lgplveiok3203kov0303vojIJVO

    FloatLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        padding: 5
        spacing: 5
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            text: "+ Добавить новый блокнот"
            font_size: 25
            background_color: (0.7,0.8,0.1,1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.8,0.9,0.2,1)
            on_release:
                root.create_notebook()

#krmbfgrlp45-lh5-hkogkr94jg94gpoekfp309
```

В общем я думаю, что есть какой-то более простой и изящный способ, как можно реализовать такое в киви, и очень хотел бы его узнать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил эту проблему через два метода(on_pre_enter и on_leave). В on_pre_enter циклом прохожусь по количеству заметок (count_notes) и добавляю кнопки.
При выходе с экрана (on_leave) очищаю список виджетов.

Примеры функций:

```
def on_pre_enter(self):
    count_notes = crud_operations.count_notes()
    for i in range(0, count_notes):
        button = Button()
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(button) # Добавляем кнопку
        # Добавляем действие когда кнопка нажата. 
        # Необходимо будет в классе создать метод pressed.
        button.bind(on_press=self.pressed)  

def on_leave(self):  # Будет вызвана в момент закрытия экрана
    self.ids.grid.clear_widgets() # Очищает экран заметок
```

Comment: хоть уже и не актуально для меня, но всё-равно спасибо за ответ, может другим поможет!